# Weblogic managed server failing

Tags: svn, caching, weblogic

I have a project at my company that's using maven to compile and weblogic as the server. Of course everything must be tested locally before the QA server release, and finally the live site release, so we all have a local weblogic server installed. My changes involved only drools. The problem is my project compiles correctly but I get exceptions as I start my managed server. After my managed server starts, naturally my project doesn't display. Every data source is triple checked and tested and is working perfectly fine. I reverted changes to the working SVN version (the one everyone else is using fine) and still the issue. I completely (manually) erased the Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains folder and rebuilt everything with a freshly downloaded (also erased the SVN folder) version of the project and still no results. The exception is the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘….’ defined in URL [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/…/servers/ManagedServer/tmp/_WL_user/portal/2e5zyc/war/WEB-INF/lib/…-core-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/module/….rules.xml]
```

This error is shown with various beans I didn’t modify. After a few of these, the actual exception continues as:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is [Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.getechnologiesmx…...Conduct()] [Near : {... payment.conduct == Conduct.CREDIT_CARD|| pa ....}]
```

I can’t give out too much code because of company policies but it mentions possible autowiring issues, which I also did not modify. I modified some pom xmls to point to my directories from a friends project (the same code that is working fine for him) to point to where I have my drools, reports, etc., compiled, uploaded the WARS on my admin server, and still the exact same exception. They are the same directories I have always used (I've had no problems before, everything used to work fine). I'm working on a 64bit Windows 7 laptop, core i5, 6GBs RAM, 1TB HDD, and my version of weblogic is 10.3.5.0 with jdk 1.6 EE. I have a feeling it's a cache related issue, but I don't know what else to erase. If it is, how can I clear it, if it isn't what else can I do?

Comment: Generally the unable to resolve method error is a class cast issue. Try setting `System.setProperty("drools.dialect.mvel.strict", "false");` to see if that gets around it.

Comment: Where do I set that? in the project that uses the drools, or in my weblogic? And why did it work before without ever touching that?

Comment: Never mind, tried it, and if failed anywayz, same error :S